# How to add a custom tap handler on a custom SwiftUI View?

Tags: swiftui

```
List {
   ItemView(item: item)
       .myCustomTapHandler {
           print("ItemView was tapped, triggered from List!")         
       }
   }
}

struct ItemView: View {
    var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
           // this should fire myCustomTapHandler
        }) {
            Text("Hello world")
        }
        
    }
}
```

I have a custom `ItemView` with a simple button. I want to re create the same trailing closure syntax as `.onTapGesture`, with only triggering when you tap the `Button`. This will be named `.myCustomTapHandler` How to do this in SwiftUI?

Comment: so you want button action from button to list view ?

Comment: @RajaKishan i clearified with a comment now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing (The dot) is a `ViewModifier`

```
struct MyItemListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            //Using a ViewModifier you make the whole View tappable not just the button
            MyItemView(item: 2)
                .myCustomTapHandler{
                    print("ItemView has custom modifier that makes the whole ItemView tappable")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct MyCustomTapHandler: ViewModifier {
    var myCustomTapHandler: () -> Void
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            //Add the onTap to the whole View
            .onTapGesture {
                myCustomTapHandler()
            }
    }
}
extension View {
    func myCustomTapHandler(myCustomTapHandler: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        modifier(MyCustomTapHandler(myCustomTapHandler: myCustomTapHandler))
    }
}
```

The `ViewModifier` affects the entire View not just the `Button`.

But, unless you are doing something else it is just an `onTapGesture`.

This is likely not the best solution because with the `Button` in the `ItemView` you will have inconsistent results.

Sometimes the `Button` will get the tap and sometimes the `ViewModifier` will get the tap and given that the `View` is in a `List` it will likely make the whole tapping confusing because the `List` has properties that make the whole row tappable anyway vs just the `Text` of the `Button

If you want the `Button` to perform an action that is defined in the ListView you can pass it as a parameter.

This will likely give you the best results.

```
struct MyItemListView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //This passes the custom action to the button
            MyItemView(item: 1){
                print("Button needs to be tapped to trigger this")
            }
        }
    }
}
struct MyItemView: View {
    let item: Int
    var myCustomTapHandler: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                myCustomTapHandler()
            }) {
                Text("Hello world")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add like this.

```
struct ItemView: View {
    
    private var action: (() -> Void)? = nil

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                action?()
            }) {
                Text("Hello world")
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    func myCustomTapHandler(onAction: @escaping () -> Void) -> Self {
        var view = self
        view.action = onAction
        return view
    }
}
```

Usage

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ItemView()
            .myCustomTapHandler {
                print("Hello word")
            }
    }
}
```

---

---

Another way is...

I don't think with dot property you will get action. You need closure inside the ItemView.

Like this

```
struct ItemView: View {
    
    var action: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: action) {
                Text("Hello world")
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
List {
    ItemView {
        // Here you will get action
        print("ItemView was tapped, triggered from List!")
    }
}
```